# random forest : low sensitivity

Tags: r, tidyverse, random-forest, tidymodels

I'm using Random Forest (in R, tidyverse model). When testing my training model, I've observed a notably low sensitivity value. Could you suggest a solution to enhance the sensitivity value?

.metric              .estimator .estimate
                          
1 accuracy             binary         0.744
2 kap                  binary          0.391
3 sens                 binary          0.511
4 spec                 binary          0.860

I searched similar issue (low specificity and high sensitivity) and saw this advice about that: “you could always increase specificity (while decreasing sensitivity) by increasing the threshold required for "Test +" from 0.5 to some larger value (e.g. 0.7 or 0.8).”

Q1. I hope to apply this method conversely, but I don't know the exact script for this. Could you provide the script or instructions to execute this ("increasing the threshold required for "Test +" from 0.5 to some larger value (e.g. 0.7 or 0.8)")?
Q2. Or could you suggest other methods I might explore to address low sensitivity?